# Backbone.js + GUI: do i have to build the gui with views and models or do I load it with the html from start

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js

so far i only have created small test applications, and I don't really know or get how to use backbone.js best for a full blown app's GUI.

i see even the smallest example on the backbone.js documentation:

```
var Sidebar = Backbone.Model.extend({
  promptColor: function() {
    var cssColor = prompt("Please enter a CSS color:");
    this.set({color: cssColor});
  }
});

window.sidebar = new Sidebar;

sidebar.bind('change:color', function(model, color) {
  $('#sidebar').css({background: color});
});

sidebar.set({color: 'white'});

sidebar.promptColor();
```

does this mean that i have to wrap every element of my GUI into a model and a view for it?
or would that be concidered bad practice?

i have a feeling this would be overly complex, and i would very well be able to just load the gui already in the html file, and make models / views for only the elements of the gui that require dynamic content.

> **to state the question clearly: is it a good idea to build your gui
>   trough models / views?  if so do you create 1 global view? or really
>   build up every element in a view? (header / sidebar / navigationbar /
>   content area / footer / whatever more...)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is largely an "it depends" question, unfortunately. it depends on what your application needs to do, how much control you need over the HTML via the backbone objects, etc.

i don't think you're going to find "the right answer" to this question, as it's very subjective.

instead, i recommend you keep playing with backbone to find what implementations work for you, and when, while looking a the existing sample apps in the backbone documentation for ideas.

i also highly recommend you buy the Peepcode and Tekpub screencasts for backbonejs. they are worth every penny. if you're not doing any asp.net mvc 3 work on the back-end, you can probably skip the tekpub mvc 3 series (where the backbone episode is).

there are also a lot of great blog posts and reference implementations out there if you search for them.

Comment: all right, i can agree that my question is most likely not the most easy to answer, its not a matter of yes or no, more like yes or no, but...    however i will take your advice on those screencasts, actual .net developer the asp.net mvc backend does interest me as well. thanks for the tip!

Comment: ah, then i would say you should spend the $ on the Tekpub series, first. the entire mvc 3 series of brilliant, and it covers more than just code. it's everything you need for a real-world app. episode 6, specifically, covers backbone and integrating it with asp.net mvc backend.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone's presentation layer is mostly convention based, rather then providing a rich hierarchy of predefined widgets and layout managers like traditional gui framework Backbone does not do anything at all to create your GUI, besides providing a recommended structure for modularizing the view layer into loosely coupled, independent sections which can auto-update to respond to user actions or model updates. 
To what level you should modularize is entirely up to you. You can build your own hierarchy of nested views eg. a sidebar view containing top toolbar and bottom toolbar view and a list view occupying the main body and this list view will further comprise of list item views which can be rendered. 
Whether you should go to this level of granularity entirely depends on your needs. For instance, if the list of navigational links in your sidebar is static and never changing, then this level of nesting of views is simply an overkill. But however, if your listview is attached to a collection or you need a nested tree of related items which are incrementally fetched from the server then the above approach is the way to go. 
The thumb rule is factor your presentation layer into view classes only till it aids in convenience.